# How to open two different LaTeX documents with TeX Maker, simultaneously?

Tags: texmaker

I am going to transfer a lengthy paper from template `A` to template `B`; and one could imagine that such stuff will be fascinated, considerably, if I could open each template within an independent `TeX Maker` session and transfer the content from `A` to `B`, gradually.

But as I try to open the secondary document, the `TeX Maker`, primarily, just closes the prior one, was which already open.

One might assert that I can open `A` in the other editor, just like notepad, but I am keen on handle this case, potentially, by `TeX Maker`, solely.

Comment: I think that you will find more help on http://superuser.com or some other site that is about software and editors.

Comment: I assume that either TeXMaker has the ability to use multiple "buffers" (to use Emacs-speak) or it doesn't.... Other editors certain can do this. In Emacs, you simply command it to be so with `C-x 3` for side-by-side or `C-x 2` for top-and-bottom.

Comment: in Texmaker you have a Source viewer. menu:view->Source viewer

Comment: you can see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6hDE-psV4Q&feature=youtu.be